# how can I save some part of decodable struct that json has parsed into that into the UserDefaults in swift 4?

Tags: json, swift, struct, swift4, nsuserdefaults

so here is my struct that I will parse my json into that

```
public struct Response : Decodable {
    var Data : [Data]?
    let Status : Int?
    let Message : String?
}
public struct Data : Decodable {
    let id : String?
    let full_name : String?
    let is_private : String?
    let profile_pic_url : String?
    let username : String?
    let biography : String?
    let type : String?
    let code : String?
    let date : String?
    let thumbnail_src : String?
    let display_src : String?
    let caption : String?
    let detail : String?
    let type_id : String?
    let district_id : String?
    let p_name : String?
}
```

and here I made an object from my Data struct

```
public class publicVariables {
    static var savedItems = [listPageModel.Data]()
}
```

and here is the method when my app launches for first time or not

```
func setDefults() {
    let launchedBefore = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "launchedBefore")
    if launchedBefore  {
        print("Not first launch.")


        let decoded  = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "savedPosts") as! Data
        let decodedTeams = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: decoded)  as! [listPageModel.Data]
        publicVariables.savedItems = decodedTeams

    } else {

        print("First launch, setting UserDefault.")
        UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "launchedBefore")

        let encodedData: Data = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: publicVariables.savedItems)
        UserDefaults.standard.set(encodedData, forKey: "savedPosts")
        UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()


    }
}
```

and then I parse the json to the struct

```
var res : listPageModel.Response? = nil
var mainData = [listPageModel.Data]()
.
.
.
self.res = try JSONDecoder().decode(listPageModel.Response.self , from : data!)
 for i in 0...((self.res?.Data?.count)!) - 1 {
                            self.mainData.append((self.res?.Data?[i])!)
.
.
.
```

so now we have the json decoded into the struct and I can show that in table view or collection view now I want when user select of of them that index store into the userDefaults for example this

```
self.res?.Data[0]
```

so I used this method here

```
@objc func likeDislike(_ sender : UIButton!) {
    print(sender.tag)
    if !publicVariables.savedItems.contains(where: {$0.code! == "\(self.res?.Data[sender.tag].code)"}) {

        print((self.mainData[sender.tag].caption)!)
        publicVariables.savedItems.append((self.mainData[sender.tag]))
        let encodedData: Data = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: [publicVariables.savedItems])
        publicVariables().defaults.set(encodedData, forKey: "savedPosts")
        publicVariables().defaults.synchronize()

    } else {

        print((self.mainData[sender.tag].caption)!)
        let encodedData: Data = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: [publicVariables.savedItems])
        publicVariables().defaults.set(encodedData, forKey: "savedPosts")
        publicVariables().defaults.synchronize()

    }
}
```

But when this functions will run I will receive this error and the app will crash

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[_SwiftValue encodeWithCoder:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f8eda563be0'
*** First throw call stack:
```

Comment: Are you aware that `Data` is a Swift class, I don’t know if that is the issue here but it’s hard to understand what it means when you reference the `Data` type in your struct declaration, maybe the compiler gets as confused as I do. My suggestion is to rename the struct, if nothing else it will I improve readability.

Comment: look Imagine that you parsed the json into decodable struct so I want for example store self.res?.Data[0] into my UserDefaults

Comment: I don’t think you understood what I wrote. Also, why did you exclude the stack trace from the error message? Doesn’t it tell you at what line in the code the error occurred?

Comment: You are mixing up `NSCoding` with `Codable`. `NSKeyedArchiver` belongs to `NSCoding` and can be used only for sub**classes** of `NSObject`. And why are all struct members optional? Don't declare them all globally as optional. Declare only those members as optional whose key can be missing or whose JSON value can be `null`. And – as Joakim already mentioned – rename your `Data` struct. It will clash with the built-in `Data` struct.

Comment: @JoakimDanielsonthe Error will Occurred in this line 
            let encodedData: Data = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: [publicVariables.savedItems])

Comment: @vadianAll of the Optionals variables can be null so I have to used optional for them and I get confused for NSCoding and NSKeyArchiver can you help me please step by step ?

Comment: I don't believe that all struct members can be `nil`. You have to adopt `Encodable` and use `JSONEncoder` or `PropertyListEncoder`, `NSKeyedArchiver` doesn't support structs.

Comment: so can I convert that Struct to an object to use that in userDefaults ?